# increment php variable used in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables, increment

I wanted to display a graph in javascript using data from php. My code is:

```
<?php $i = 20; ?>
while (data.length < totalPoints) {
    array_js.push(<?php echo json_encode($array_php[++$i][1]);?>);
}
```

The problem is that even though $i is declared before the while loop, it gets back to 20 all the time, so the data pushed in array_js is always $array_php[21][1].

Edit: here is more code, (not same variable name...)

```
startConn(); //connect to database

$query = "SELECT * FROM Reading";
$data = getAllDatas($query);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

    var data = [], totalPoints = 300;

        function getRandomData() {

            <?php $i = 20; ?>
            while (data.length < totalPoints) {
                data.push(<?php echo json_encode($data[--$i][1]);?>);
                //data.push(<?php echo ++$i;?>);
            }
        } // END getRandomData()
```

Comment: You can't mix php and javascript in this way. What is your goal? Why you want read a php array in javascript?

Comment: to display a graph in javascript using data from php

Comment: why not just encode your php array from the start, then make your way into pushing whatever values you have there

Comment: can show you more code? the javascript reside in html page, I suppose. Javascript can't use php data. you have to set the complete javascript array in php. but if you show more code, we can be more accurate

Comment: The problem is not the php array. I want to walk through the php array and to do that I need to increment $i and it seems that I am not able to achieve that because it does reset automatically.

Comment: PHP is done by the time JS code is run. It would be better if you tell us what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Rossygnol please take a look at source of html in **our browser** to understand the output of your javascript

Comment: You have to set the complete javascript array in php, then the javascript function have to select random value from his **own** array

Comment: @Rossygnol - the PHP runs _on your server_ and the javascript is _not running at all_ during that time. When the PHP is done running, the results are sent to the browser; at that time _there is no more PHP_ — it's _gone_, and _then_ the javascript starts running _in the browser_. The PHP and the javascript are running at two separate times in two different places. Prove it to yourself: create a simple `.php` from some tutorial, look at it in a browser, then use the browser's _"View Page Source"_; you'll see there is no PHP left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding on how server side and client side code work.
I think this may help you

```
$(function() {
    var data = [], totalPoints = 3;
    var i = <?php $i = 1;echo $i; ?>;
    var j = parseInt(i);
    var arr = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

    function getRandomData() {
        while (data.length < totalPoints) {
            data.push(arr[j][1]);
            j++;
        }
        return data;
    }
    var data1 = getRandomData();
    console.log(data1);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfect. I didn't know that it was possible to pass more complex variables like multidimensional arrays. My lack of knowledge in javascript doesn't help. should probably spend some time learning it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You can pass the value of the php variable using echo while declaring another variable on the java script.

```
<?php $i = 20; ?>
var i = <?php echo $i;?>;
while (data.length < totalPoints) {
    array_js.push(<?php echo json_encode($array_php[++i][1]);?>);
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried your code but I doubt it will work since 'i' cannot be seen in a php code. Might be wrong though...